# Generating batches of n-dimensional Perlin noise using Python and NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, perlin-noise

I managed to grasp the way Perlin noise works and implement a pixel-at-a-time version using [this](http://www.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf) awesome PDF as a reference, but, quite obviously it's incredibly slow.

First thought would be to generate it as batches - instead going through every pixel from 0.0 to 1.0, generate a `numpy.linspace` and then act on it using numpy's vectorised operations, but this seems to be beyond me, I keep getting lost and deleting everything I wrote.

Could a kind StackOverflower help me? As little as example code and as much as detailed explanation of every step would both help me greatly.

**EDIT:** By batches I mean arrays containing values of perlin noise at different points in space, as opposed to my noise() method only generating one pixel at a time.

Comment: Can you clarify your "batches" idea?  I don't know anything about Perlin noise itself, but I might be able to help anyway.  Were you trying to pre-generate the textures and then interpolate them onto the target surface?

Comment: By batches I mean more than one pixel at a time, e.g an array containing noise that I can later use instead of generating it pixel by pixel, calling python functions every time.

Comment: Ahh - I see, so you are trying to use the vectorisation of numpy and it is not not going well.  This isn't so unusual.  Is your code simple enough that you can post it somewhere that we can look at it?   If the thing really is complicated, you might be better of writing a function in C that does the job pixel-at-a-time and then wrapping it in a vectorized python function.

Answer (score 1):

If guess correctly, then Asmagedon wants to per-calculate his noise textures and then later paint them onto some other target of a different size.

One way to do this is with [scipy.signal.resample](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) which can both interpolate and subsample a signal.  From memory it only works on one dimension at a time -- just loop over the dimensions.

There are probably better ways to do antialiasing, but this one is easy.